# I am getting 404 error after performing ajax request in my laravel project.please help me

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, slug

[Error image][1]

**plase see my error page console log**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8c5X.png

all looks good but I can't find the exact error,
**My route file**
**route.php**

```
Route::get('/story/checkSlug', 'StoryController@checkSlug');
```

**In blade file**

```html
 <div class="form-row">
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="title"><strong>Slug</strong><span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                <input
                                                    class="form-control"
                                                    type="text"
                                                    placeholder="Auto Generated Slug"
                                                    name="slug"
                                                    id="slug"
                                                    value="{{ old('slug') }}">
                                            </div>
                                            @if ($errors->has('slug'))
                                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('slug') }}</span>
                                            @endif
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

```html
<script>
        $('#title').change(function(e) {
            $.get(' {{url('/story/checkSlug') }}',
                {'title':$(this).val()},
                function (data){
                    $('#slug').val(data.slug);
                }
            );
        });
    </script>
```

**Story Model**

```
<?PHP

 namespace App;

 use Conner\Tagging\Taggable;
 use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;



  class Story extends Model
 {

use Taggable;
use Sluggable;
protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'slug',
    'img_name',
    'body'
];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

/**
 * Return the sluggable configuration array for this model.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function sluggable()
{
    return [
        'slug' => [
            'source' => 'title'
        ]
    ];
}



}
```

**StoryController.php**

```
 public function checkSlug(Request $request){
    $slug = SlugService::createSlug(Story::class,'slug',$request->title);
    return response()->json(['slug'=>$slug]);

}
```

I have tried changing the url in the ajax call  but am still getting the same 404 error

Thanks guys.

Comment: That `easylearnbd.com` in your URL doesn't look right. Does this work if you go to `http://localhost/story/checkSlug`?

Comment: Hello Jewel. First, you need to check the output of blade, so what is writen down in JS code. Because you injected php code to JS code, it's not best practice. So; check the final JS code the browser trying to run. Browser says it can not find the specified URL, so you need to check if the final url really works when you try to reach it. Those are first steps to follow.

Comment: @UğurArıcı This code `$.get(' {{url('/story/checkSlug') }}',` is valid if the `<script>` is in a `.blade.php` file :)

Comment: @TimLewis easylearnbd.com this url works file in my other controller

Comment: @TimLewis I didn't say it isn't valid, I said it is not best practice :) Means; "You can mix JS and PHP but you shouldn't."

Comment: @UğurArıcı Ah yes, good call; my bad, I misread that :)

Comment: @UğurArıcı sir i didnt heart you, i say jsut it works fine, but my ajax request response getting error. the title value pass URL just like /story/checkSlug?title=dgfg%20dgffdgd